# What is causing the position of this div to change?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NS7s/)

I am trying to get these 4 divs to sit on the same vertical line. Why does the presence of buttons change the position of the first div?

HTML

```
<div class="box">
        <button>Y</button> <button>N</button>
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

RESULT

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:bottom` to the style of your `div`s.

The cause of your problem is the presence of any content, as it defines the baseline for the `div`.

Comment: And this is why I hate inline-block. "Oh, I'm inline." "Oh, I'm block." "No, INLINE!" "NO! BLOCK!"

Comment: Yes, yes, `inline-block` means "inline from the outside, block from the inside". From the CSS 2.1 spec: "This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box." It still annoys me.

Answer (score -2):

[jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9NS7s/1/)

Just change the display property of the div's and they'll align vertically:

`display: block`

Edit: @ben said he wanted the div's aligned vertically. Vote me down if you must, but it's not my fault if he didn't know the difference between horizontal and vertical.

Comment: `display:block` is default, and clearly NOT what the OP wants.

Comment: True, but he said, "I am trying to get these 4 divs to sit on the same vertical line." His CSS was `display:inline-block`. Changing it to `block` produces the desired vertical alignment.

Comment: Except for the fact that the divs in your solution are no longer on the same line. Take some context from the screenshot.

Comment: "I am trying to get these 4 divs to sit on the same vertical line."

And ignore the context of the description? Miscommunication begets miscommunication.

Answer (score -2):

Adjusting the css like this works

```
.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
div.box{display:inline;float:left;}
```

Comment: This will prevent the OP from using further block-level elements inside, which presumably he will want to do. And it would also require `clear`ing the float afterwards.

Comment: Actually, not quite. An inline element that has `float` applied to it (if I remember my specs correctly - [and I do](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)) will be displayed as if it were block. So, really, applying `inline` as well as `float` does *nothing* to a block-level element.